# float of the background-image

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I have the `<div>` with `background-image` css rule.
**Html**

```
<div class="myclass">Hello world</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myclass
{
    background-image: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    border: 1px red dotted;
}
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqeTx/)

How can I make background-image inside div to float the text?

P.S:I cann't create another `div` (or another element) inside the currrent `div`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zqeTx/2/

Comment: Use `text-indent: 20px` or `padding-left: 20px` .

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zqeTx/8/)..

Comment: @Mr_Green you should add your solution and the fiddle as a possible answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add padding to the `div` to shift the text.

```
.myclass
{
    background-image: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    border: 1px red dotted;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zqeTx/1/

Comment: Actually this does not wrap the text around the image it just adds some padding to the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [::before pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore).

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/zqeTx/7/)

```
.myclass:before
{
    background-image: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

The advantage of this method is that if there's a long text with multiple lines it will indent the text only on the first line.

[**Multiple lines jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/zqeTx/6/)

Comment: This is a neat solution. Can't think of another way of achieving this, but sadly it's not compatible with IE versions of 9 and below.

Comment: @manticore I've updated my answer to use `:before` instead of `::before`. This is supported on `IE8+`.

Comment: I think you didn't get the thought of `text-indent` :)

Comment: +1 - In this case, as there's no sprite involved, you can simplify it to this: `content: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');`, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/KDXxV/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cann't use it, because it doesn't work in IE7:(

Comment: @mr_green I was referring the padding solution

Answer (score 2):

Add [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) css property and also pin the background image to top so that if the text goes to second line, the background will not move.

```
.myclass {
    background-image: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:2px 2px;
    border: 1px red dotted;
    text-indent:20px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zqeTx/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS 
[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/FjWG8/)

```
.myclass
{   
    border: 1px red dotted;
}
.myclass:before
{
    background-image: url('http://www.europe-trip.cz/icons/spinner.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    content:'';
}
```